# How to return more than one value from a C++ function?

Tags: c++, number-theory

I am interested if I can return more then one value from a function. For example consider such a function: extended euclidean algorithm. The basic step is described by this
Input is nonnegative integers a and b;
output  is a triplet (d,i,j) such that `d=gcd(a,b)=i*a+j*b`.
Just to clarify my question's goal I will write a short recursive code:

```
 if (b==0)  return (a,1,0)
      q=a mod b;
```

let r be such that  `a=r*b+q;`

```
(d,k,l)=extendedeuclidean(b,q);
  return (d,l,k-l*r);
```

How does one return a triplet?

Comment: Consider using punctuation next time. This is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an appropriate data structure holding the three values and return that.

```
struct extmod_t {
    int d;
    int i;
    int j
    extmod_t(int d, int i, int j) : d(d), i(i), j(j) { }
};

…

extmod_t result = extendedeuclidean(b, q);
return extmod_t(result.d, l, k - l * r);
```

Comment: just one question  how to  do it when there is recursive calling of function?

Comment: @user466534 What do you mean? There is no special handling required for recursion.

Answer (score 8):

You could create a `std::tuple` or [boost::tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) (if you don't use C++0x) from your triple pair and return that.

Answer (score 2):

As has been suggested by Tony The Tiger you can use [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Tuple_types). It is included in C++11 standard and new compilers already support it. It is also implemented in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html).
For my ibm xlC compiler tuple is in std::tr1 namespace (tried it for MSVC10 — it's in std namespace).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>

// for MSVC
using namespace std;

// for xlC 
//using namespace std::tr1;

// for boost
// using namespace boost;

typedef tuple<int, float, char> MyTuple;
MyTuple f() {
    return MyTuple(1, 2.0f, '3');
}

int main() {
    MyTuple t = f();
    printf("%i, %f, %c\n", get<0>(t), get<1>(t), get<2>(t));
}
```

xlC compilation for TR1:

```
xlC -D__IBMCPP_TR1__ file.cpp
```

xlC compilation for boost:

```
xlC file.cpp -I/path/to/boost/root
```

Answer (score 0):

Either create a class that encapsulates the triplet and then return the instance of this class, or use 3 by-reference parameters.

Comment: –1 for by-reference parameters. This is a horrible abuse of parameters and entirely unnecessary and makes the function less convenient to use.

Comment: @Konrad It makes it less convenient to use only if the caller is already prepared to use the object. If the rest of the code uses independent fields, then "unpacking" the returned object may actually be uglier than just directly passing the fields by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find that when I need to return two parameters from a function, it is useful to use the `STL` `std::pair`.

You could always stack the pairs inside one another (e.g. `std::pair <int, std::pair <int, int> >`) and help your self with typedef-s or defines to make it more accessible, but when ever I try doing this my code ends up messy and unpractical for re-use.

For more than two parameters, however, I recommend making you own specific data structure that holds the information you need (if you are returning multiple values there's a high likelihood that they are strongly logically connected somehow and that you might end up using the same structure again).

E.g. I needed a function that returned the slope of the line (1 param) and that was fine. Then I needed to expand it to return both parameters of the parametric representation of the line (`y = k*x + l`). Two parameters, still fine. Then I remembered that the line can be vertical and that I should add another parameter to indicate that (no parametric representation then)... At this point, it became too complicated to try and make do with existing datatypes, so I typed up my own Line structure and ended up using the same structure all over my project later.